# Custom Customer Fields in checkout

Tags: customer, onepage-checkout, custom-options

I've succesfully managed to add custom fields to the customer. However I need these fields to show up in onepage checkout.

I've overridden `Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Name` and created my own `customer/widget/name.phtml`, added the attributes in  the `sql/xxx_setup/installer-x.y.z.php` (added them to `adminhtml_customer`, `customer_account_edit`, `checkout_register` and `customer_account_create`) and they work fine in the admin site, however they just wont work on the checkout form. The field shows up, but it has the wrong value and no label.

I'm clueless why does it work in the customer registration form but doesn't in the checkout.

The installer code to add the attribute is:

```
$attributes = array(
    'lastname2' =>  array(
        'frontend_label'=>'Apellido Materno',
        'label' => 'Apellido Materno',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        //System =  False and visible true = Show in 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'
        'system'=>true,
        'visible'=>true, //Watch out!! Only visible fields get processed by the form controllers!!!
        'user_defined'=>false,
        'used_in_forms' => array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register','customer_account_create'),
        'required' => 0,
        'position' =>69
    ));


foreach($attributes as $attribute_code=>$definition)
    {
        $installer->addAttribute('customer', $attribute_code,  $definition); 

        /**
        * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Config
        */
        Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', $attribute_code)
        ->setData('used_in_forms',$definition['used_in_forms'])
        ->save();
    }
```

The code in name.phtml is

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getContainerClassName()?>">
    <?php if ($this->showPrefix()): ?>
        <div class="field name-prefix">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>"<?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php if ($this->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($this->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getPrefix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-firstname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field name-middlename">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname2')?>"><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname2') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname2')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname2')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname2()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname2') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname2') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if ($this->showSuffix()): ?>
        <div class="field name-suffix">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>"<?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php if ($this->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix')?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($this->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getSuffix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `'frontend_label'=>'Apellido Materno'` it is the same as `label`. What do you mean by "the wrong value"? Change the attribute system to 0 and check in the backend, what the label is on the customer page. And check the `eav_attribute` and `customer_eav_attribute` for the attribute. Does it exist? Theoretically the label should be used, if you don't define a storeView label, but in my experience, sometimes it doesn't. So fix this error or define a storeview label.

Comment: Ur right about `frontend_label`. By wrong value I mean it shows me the value of `lastname`, not `lastname2`. The attribute is set to `system=>yes` so it wont show automatically on the forms wherever it wants to, but rather where I manually put it (yes I tried `visible=>no`, but then it doesn't get processed). The attribute does exist, it works fine in the customer registration and in the customer admin panel. It just wont work in the onepage checkout. My gut feeling is that I need to add that attribute to another entity as well (I tried to add it to `customer/address` but it didnt work either)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug here:

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname2')?>" 
name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname2')?>" 
value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname2') ?>" maxlength="255"...
```

Have a look on `$this->getObject()->getLastname()` should be `$this->getObject()->getLastname2()`

Comment: Fabian. yes a friend pointed that out for me this morning. That explains the wrong value. Once that got fixed, the wrong value is gone, and nothing shows up :(

Comment: What do you mean? Nothing? No value? Is the value in the database? And is it loaded?

Comment: The vealue is in the DB. And the customer has the value. I'm starting to think I should create the lastname2 attribute in customer/address??

Comment: My guess is, that the collection doesn't load the value or the customer doesn't

Comment: A Collection there? Now I'm lost. Can you explain, please?
(the customer is loading the second last name, because I can get it everywhere else)

Comment: If you can everything except the lastname2 it is not loaded. customers are eav. So the question is, what type is $this->getObject(), where is it loaded and is the lastname2 loaded too :) Happy digging.