# Adding custom customer fields to One Page Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I have been struggling with this for quite some time.

I have a one page checkout (IWD), and on it I have 2 custom fields that I want the user to fill in. The fields already show, and validation happens. The one page checkout is a form that works on ajax (I'm not sure if it's the theme or the actual one page checkout, I was handed this project when it was almost finished).

Guest checkout is disabled, so in order to check out, the user has to fill in the billing address (which contain the two fields) and that then registers the user.

When a user submits this form, with these two fields filled in, I get an alert back that says the two fields are required. Now my thinking is as follows: Since it passes validation on the front end and fails on the back end, the fields aren't being submitted to user registration. These fields are required in user registration. I created the fields with [Custom Registration Fields](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custome-account-profile-13594.html) and set it to required in the admin section.

How would I go about getting these fields to post to the user registration? I've tried [setting the user session and including these fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58305/add-custom-field-to-iwd-one-page-checkout-extension). I've also read through this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10388/custom-customer-fields-in-checkout).

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab post data by 
`$this->getRequest()->getPost('field_name', array());`

You will need to change `field_name` to your desired name in `.phtml` file.

For example;

```
<input type="text" name="field_name[data_1]" value="customer_input_1">
<input type="text" name="field_name[data_2]" value="customer_input_2">
```

Then to retrieve those data use following:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('field_name', array());
$customer_input_1 = $data[data_1];
$customer_input_2 = $data[data_2];
```

I believe, in order to record these data, you will need to create new table or column within existing magento tables.

Comment: Data is already being recorded on customer registration. Problem is, when you register using onepagecheckout, these values aren't posted to customer register

Comment: If that's the case then you will have to use your observer to send data to tables. See this [link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/).